# Portable CDI extension to inject beans at runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, weld, jboss-weld

Referencing this: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html_single/#_the_literal_injectiontarget_literal_interface

Following the instructions from above, i am able to load `SomeFrameworkComponent.class` dynamically at runtime via some custom `ClassLoader`. It looks like this:

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public CustomClassLoader() {

    }

    public Class defineClass(String location, byte[] classData, String name) {

        java.nio.file.Path p = java.nio.file.Paths.get(location);

        try {
            return defineClass(name, Files.readAllBytes(p), 0, classData.length);
        } catch (ClassFormatError | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

After that i follow the steps exactly from `16.5. The InjectionTarget interface` and it all works. However if i change the .class file and reload it, CDI will return the old one every time. The new class is correctly reloaded, because when i call `newInstance()` on the class returned from `defineClass`, it be an instance of the updated class as expected.

If i understand correctly, once a bean is registered, it is put (bound) in a `Context`, which is a container for beans. Subsequent requests for that bean will retrieve it from that container. And if i want to be able to destroy it at will or for every request get a new one from a new .class file, i will have to create a custom `Context` that will support this. Right?

If my assumptions are correct, then how do i specify programmatically my custom `Context` that the .class object is supposed to go?

Comment: How are you registering the `SomeFrameworkComponent` as a bean in the first place? Is it annotated with scope? otherwise it defaults to `Dependent` scope, which simply means that it lasts as long as the bean to which it is injected into last.

Comment: It's just a POJO, no annotations, so it gets the default scope. Which is why i need to a custom `Context` implementation, right? Registration happens via injected `BeanManager`, just like it is jboss weld spec link: createAnnotatedType(...) ; createInjectionTarget(...) ; createCreationalContex(null) ...

Comment: Hmm, if I get what you are trying (e.g. re-load class during runtime and expect new bean), then this won't work with CDI. There are metadata (annotated types, bean attributes) which are created once, usually on deploy, and then stored and re-used. CDI does not re-scan the classes again to produce new metadata on each injection (it would be very expensive). I can think of no way to force re-creation of those.

Comment: BTW I can also think of several ways that your approach would break functionality. For instance, changing the class to use `@Specializes` or `@Alternative`, then reloading it would either have to malfunction, or re-boot whole CDI container to be able to determine actually enabled beans.

Comment: But that is not its purpose. It's purpose is to simply be given DI services so that when it sees `@Inject`, it will deliver. Code already running (deployment-time code) will be agnostic to this. CDI spec has explicitly provided a `SPI` and `BeanManager` enables runtime class loading and instantiation. Why shouldn't it be able to work in reverse and forget that `.class`? Or even better - not remember it at all. Just take a `.class`'s bytes, create **transient** `AnnotatedType`, `BeanAttributes`, `InjectionTargetFactory`, and the `Bean`; via `BeanManager:getContext()` choose where to go...